# Finding poles of $\frac{1}{1 + z^4}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{1 + z^4}$$

has poles when $z^4 + 1 = 0$

$\implies (z^2 + i)(z^2 - i) = 0$

$\implies (z^2 - i) = 0$ when $z = \sqrt{i}$ or $z = -\sqrt{i}$.

But how do I solve the equation $(z^2 + i) = 0$?

Thanks.

Comment: If $z=i$ is $z^2-i=0?$ Pretty sure that's wrong.

Comment: It is not true that $\;z^2-i=0\implies z=\pm i\;$ ...you must calculate both square roots of $\;i\;$ , and of $\;-i\;$ for $\;z^2=i=0\;$ .

Comment: Sorry, typo! Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

$$z^4=-1=e^{i\pi}=e^{(2n+1)\pi i}$$ where $n$ is any integer

$$\implies z=e^{\dfrac{(2n+1)\pi i}4}$$ where $n\equiv0,1,2,3\pmod4$

We can use [Euler Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerFormula.html) to express $z$ in a more familiar form

Answer (score 0):

To have $z^2+i=0$ that means $z^2 = -i$. We know $e^{3i\pi/2} = -i$, so $$z^2 =e^{3i\pi/2} \\ \implies z = \pm \sqrt{e^{3i\pi/2}} \\ \implies z = \pm e^{3i\pi /4}$$

Answer (score 0):

For example:

$$z^2=-i=e^{\frac{3\pi i}2+2k\pi i}=e^{\frac{\pi i}2\left(3+4k\right)}\;\implies z=e^{\frac{\pi i}4\left(3+4k\right)}\;,\;\;k=0,1\implies$$

$$z_0=e^{\frac{3\pi i}4}=\frac1{\sqrt2}(-1+i)$$

$$z_1=e^{\frac{7\pi i}4}=\frac1{\sqrt2}(1-i)$$